# Enable CSS files in Omega 3 sub theme with Drush?

Tags: drush, theming

Is it possible to enable CSS files in an Omega 3 sub theme with Drush?

Im working locally and regularly importing the latest database from live. I have a build script that I run to clear cache, enable modules im using etc. However im manually enabling the CSS files in my theme each time. Can this be added to the build script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a bit familiar with Omega 4. In order for your css files to be "enabled" by default, you need to transfer the theme settings from the database into the theme's .info file and make sure this is enabled also in the live site. So if you have css/style.css and its declared in the .info file, Omega 4 will just follow the .info file.

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: I have an Omega 3 theme. Adding the files in the info file makes then accessible but not turned on by default.